# error in covariance via openCV calcCovarMatrix(data, covar, means, CV_COVAR_COLS);

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

It seems that [calcCovarMatrix()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=calcco#cv.CalcCovarMatrix), openCV 2.4.2 calculates means correctly but messes-up a covariance matrix. From its result I see that it may misinterpret data as rows though the flag in function arguments indicates that data are stored as columns. Here is a simple input and output of this function:

```
Mat covar, means;
Mat data = (Mat_<float>(2, 3)<<1,2, 3, 10, 20, 30);
cout<<"data:"<<endl<<data<<endl;
calcCovarMatrix(data, covar, means, CV_COVAR_COLS); // fails!
cout<<"means:"<<endl<<means<<endl;
cout<<"covar:"<<endl<<covar<<endl;
```

data:
[1, 2, 3;
10, 20, 30]
means:
[2; 20]
covar:
[101, 0, -101;
0, 0, 0;
-101, 0, 101]

I expected 2x2 covariance (since means are 2x1) but got a 3x3 matrix as if data were rows. The situation with CV_COVAR_ROWS is erroneous in the same way - calculating means correctly but covar is calculated as if data are columns.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that you MUST add either CV_COVAR_NORMAL or CV_COVAR_SCRAMBLED.
For normal behaviour use CV_COVAR_NORMAL.

So your call should be

```
calcCovarMatrix(data, covar, means, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_COLS);
```