# Confusion with OpenCV calcCovarMatrix function

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, covariance

I have observations in vector form and I want to calculate the covariance matrix and the mean from these observations in OpenCV using `calcCovarMatrix`:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

My current function call is:

```
calcCovarMatrix(descriptors.at(j).descriptor.t(), covar, mean, CV_COVAR_ROWS);
```

Whereas `descriptors.at(j).descriptor.t()` is **one** matrix with 2 columns and 390 rows. So my "random variables" are the rows of this matrix. The `covar` and `mean` are empty matrices.

The function calculates `covar` correctly and retuns a 390x390 matrix. But the `mean` is just a matrix with 1 row and 2 columns. I do not get this. I am expecting a matrix with 1 columnd and 390 rows (a column vector).

Am I using the wrong variant of the function? If yes, how should I use the correct variant in my case, I am specifically pointing to the value for the `nsamples` parameter. I don't know two what value to set it.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670640/error-in-covariance-via-opencv-calccovarmatrixdata-covar-means-cv-covar-cols. There might be a bug with that function...

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670640/error-in-covariance-via-opencv-calccovarmatrixdata-covar-means-cv-covar-cols/27066172#27066172